# Increase JVM and ANT Performance

Tags: java, memory, ant, jvm

My ANT scripts run very slow in my machine.
I want to increase runtime performance of JVM and ANT in my machine.

System Config: Intel Core i7 2.40 Ghz 
Windows 7 64 Bit
Ram: 8 GB

Java Version: 1.7.0_25 (64 bit)

I need to allocate RAM as following

ANT  - Initial- 1 GB, Max - 4 GB

JAVA - Initial 1 GB Max - 4 GB

How can set this in system variables? If you have any other pointers that also will be much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial / Max heap size in Java is set via JVM arguments `-Xms` / `-Xmx`, like this

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx4G ...
```

ant is a java app so the above applies to ant too. You need to set ANT_OPTS env variable in ant.bat

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx4G
```